# how to remain the style of GUI component after disabling it in javafx?

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx

Just to clarify things, when I disable any GUI component, e.g. labels, Their style changes slightly to indicate that they are disabled.
But I do not want that I want their style to remain the same, so How could I do that.
Note the style has gradients and colors so If there is just something that will just say do nothing to styles when disabled that would be optimal.

Edit : 
I tried to specify identifiers and make the CSS style the same for both disabled or not but I did not work Here is the code of css

```
#markedCity{
        -fx-background-color:
            linear-gradient(#ffd65b, #e68400),
            linear-gradient(#ffef84, #f2ba44),
            linear-gradient(#ffea6a, #efaa22),
            linear-gradient(#ffe657 0%, #f8c202 50%, #eea10b 100%),
            linear-gradient(from 0% 0% to 15% 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9), rgba(255,255,255,0));
        -fx-background-radius: 30;
        -fx-background-insets: 0,1,2,3,0;
        -fx-text-fill: #654b00;
        -fx-font-weight: bold;
        -fx-font-size: 1px;
        -fx-padding: 5 5 5 5;
    }
    #markedCity:disabled{
        -fx-background-color:
            linear-gradient(#ffd65b, #e68400),
            linear-gradient(#ffef84, #f2ba44),
            linear-gradient(#ffea6a, #efaa22),
            linear-gradient(#ffe657 0%, #f8c202 50%, #eea10b 100%),
            linear-gradient(from 0% 0% to 15% 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9), rgba(255,255,255,0));
        -fx-background-radius: 30;
        -fx-background-insets: 0,1,2,3,0;
        -fx-text-fill: #654b00;
        -fx-font-weight: bold;
        -fx-font-size: 1px;
        -fx-padding: 5 5 5 5;
    }
```

Then I attached the css sheet and assigned the ID but it remains the same

```
this.getStylesheets().add("./StylingCSS/City.css");
this.setId("markedCity");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the CSS selectors `:disabled` of the pseudo-classes (`button` or `Label`) for exemple, or any control you want to style:

```
button:disabled{

     //copy and paste the normal state code or modify according to the appearance you want 

}
```

Edit:

to use differents styles juste set different custom `StyleClss` names to your buttons or use `IDs`:

```
#btnA{  //Normal state

   -fx-background-color:red;  

}

#btnA:disabled{ //Disabled state

   -fx-background-color:gray;

}

#btnB{

   -fx-background-color:green;

}

#btnB:disabled{

   -fx-background-color:blue;

}
```

And in your java class set the ID of each button respectively :

```
buttonA.setId(btnA);
buttonB.setId(btnB);
```

Edit 2:

you just need to set the maximum opacity :

```
-fx-opacity:1.0;
```

Comment: What if the style changes? i.e, some button have a different style from the other and I do not know which one is different

Comment: Thanks for that but before marking it as an answer is there another way just to lock the style so it does not change?

Comment: The style won't change unless you change it manually by yourself, if you want to keep the same style in the `disabled` state, you just need to copy/paste the `normal` state style, or the one you want to keep.

Comment: Sorry but when I tried it, It did not work.
The button changes slightly as the same (becomes more transparent)